# Angular Pass Input to Ionic Modal

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic4

I have a component which takes in an Input parameter:

```
export class MapComponent implements OnInit {
   @Input() options: MapOptions<any>;
}
```

I page which opens this modal using the ionic ModalController:

```
async pickLocationModal() {
  const modal = await this.modalController.create({
    component: MapComponent
  });
  return await modal.present();
}
```

Additionally I have mapOptions stored in the page, which I would like to pass.

I can I pass my mapOptions to the Modal so the component will take it as an input?

Comment: Your question isn't clear at all. What's `modalController`? Is it your modal implementation?

Comment: Oops sorry I was using ionic I was under the impression it was built into angular it slipped my mind

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using Ionic since this is the same implementation of ionic's `ModalController`.

According to their [docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/modal#passing-data), it's possible by passing to `componentProps`:

```
async pickLocationModal() {
  const modal = await this.modalController.create({
    component: MapComponent,
    componentProps: { // <----------
      options: ...
    }
  });
  return await modal.present();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't even realize it was ionics until you said so.  I'll mark this answer as correct when the time limit elapses